# Looking for Canadian Pacific Railway worker James Edward Allan/Allen, believed to have died in Canada/USA about 1925?

Tags: united-states, census-records, death-records, canada, ontario

The last member of my family on my mother's side died in February 2014, and while alive refused to give me any information about our family or my maternal Grandfather. While my father's side is well documented (French Canadian Nadeaus), of my mother's side I only know the following:

1. A 1921 Census record my son found online at [a  tree at ancestry.com](http://trees.ancestry.com.au/tree/81402993/family) (also confirmed by helpful people here, thank you!)
2. A copy of family Baptismal/Birth Certificates of my Grandmother and Aunt that my Aunt's executor saved and later sent to me. My Aunt's certificate was also found/confirmed by the Sacred Heart Parish in Chapleau, but they said they couldn't find any further records.
3. Some family stories.

The only records my son and I could find (1921 census) indicated James immigrated in 1919 from the US to Canada and that he was employed by the Canadian Pacific Railway (CPR).

James Edward Allan (name from Aunt's Baptismal certificate) lived in Chapleau, Ontario with his wife Elizabeth Allan (nee Hayes - originally from Newfoundland, daughter of John Hayes and Jane Getheral - information from Grandmother's cert. and [Parish records](http://ngb.chebucto.org/Parish/basilica-1890-bap-sjc.shtml)) at the time of the June 1921 census along with my mother who was aged 1. The local cemeteries have a few 'Allan's, but I cannot prove any definitive link.

My Aunt's baptismal certificate which confirms she was born there in 1921, but was not included on the census for some reason.

There are two death scenarios for my Grandfather that I was told growing up:

1. Died while working for CPR
2. Died while prospecting and body was not found until spring thaw.

I was told he died when my mother was five and Aunt was four years old (1925), but my son and I cannot find any record of his death at that time anywhere.

I have - as much as possible online - investigated CPR's archives and Chapleau's local archives/library related to CPR and newspapers/obits around that time with no success. Such an event would have been newsworthy (and indeed several train accidents are exhaustively covered in the paper) but there is no mention of my Grandfather. This leads me to think the family stories are cover-ups as the older members of the family always refused to discuss him.

I have checked with the Library of Congress (in case he went back to the USA) as well as the deaths and marriage listings in Ontario, the various churches, the local mines and everywhere else I can think of with no success. I have also consulted with local genealogists (I live in Australia), who say that I simply have too little information to go on.

My Grandfather seems to have completely vanished - no records prior or after the 1921 census that we can definitively link to him - which is very frustrating.

To my knowledge, my sons and I are all that is left of the Allan family. Would be more than happy to discuss any further avenues of investigation!

---

Timeline:

- James born in USA, abt 1891 - from Canadian 1921 census

  - 1890 - Elizabeth born in St. Johns, Newfoundland - with baptism/birth certificate available (family documents). Note - Birth date from
    certificate contradicts census date
  - 1919:

    - James immigrated to Canada from USA
    - Elizabeth immigrated to Canada from USA or Newfoundland
  - Not known if/when they married - no marriage record found (listed on census as housewife)
  - 1920 First daughter born but no birth/baptism record known
  - 1921 Census record ([James Allen, 1921 Canada Census, Census Place: Chapleau, Algoma East, Ontario](http://search.ancestry.com/cgi-bin/sse.dll?db=CanCen1921&indiv=try&h=2001048)) says James was employed by the Canadian Pacific Railway (CPR) but CPR has no employee files for that area in this period
  - 1921 Second daughter born with baptism/birth certificate available (family documents)

---

Basically, I am running into the same problem as you're discussing - other than that record there is nothing else in either direction on the timeline - CPR has already informed me they have no records for that place or time period and I haven't been able to locate border crossing records for either adult.

Apologies for the mistakes - I'm not computer savvy and resorting to this out of lack of options. Was just trying to provide as much of my current research as possible.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user of this site please take its 2-minute [Tour] because its focussed Q&A format is quite different to bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites.  What we need to try and do is to identify a single question to ask; you can always ask others separately, if they do not get answered as part of answering the first question.  In this question I think you should ask "Where to find Death Record for James Edward Allan who died in Canada/USA about 1925?"  Do you have any candidate death records for anyone named James Edward Allan anywhere in the world?

Comment: A couple of notes to other readers regarding the 1921 Canada census link I added. 1) If you are in Canada, you CAN view that census, even if you do not have an active ancestry subscription. Just change the URL domain to .ca (http://search.ancestry.ca/cgi-bin/sse.dll?db=CanCen1921&indiv=try&h=2001048 ) (Libraries and Archives Canada links to ancestry.ca too). 2. You'll see that wife Elizabeth also immigrated in 1919 and has US citizenship because she was married to a US citizen. NB Newfoundland in 1921 was not part of Canada, but an independant Dominion from 1907 to 1949.

Comment: @PolyGeo - your timeline revision implies that James and Elizabeth immigrated to Canada together. Although possible (would explain why an Ontario marriage record is missing), I don't think it's a given based on the 1921 census alone. She may have immigrated from Newfoundland coincidentally in the same year as James came from the USA. A border-crossing record for him is not found at ancestry: either he came under another name, or he used a crossing point not yet digitized (maybe Sault Ste. Marie). Not sure where Elizabeth would have landed either, prob. depends on her departure point in Nfld.

Comment: Hi, All Thank you for the input.

Ancestry does have the 1921 census record of the Allan family with one daughter in Chapleau - it should be visible in the link to the tree I provided - that's where I got my concrete information from. I did attempt to add the Baptismal certificates of my grandmother, Aunt and mother to the tree, but frustratingly it didn't seem to take. It's saved on the tree but doesn't show up properly.

Apologies for the mistakes - I'm not computer savvy and resorting to this out of lack of options. Was just trying to provide as much of my current research as possible.

Comment: Danielle - we appreciate the link to the ancestry tree, but only those with active ancestry subscriptions can access it. It is better to summarize research information (within the guidelines that PolyGeo mentioned) in the question here. Could you clarify when and where  your grandparents may have married, and whether they immigrated together?

Comment: When "CPR ... informed [you that] they have no records for James", did they say that they have no/poor records for that period, or that they have good records for that period with James not among them?

Comment: G'day PolyGeo 
CPR's exact response was: "CP has no employee files from this area from this time period."

Comment: G'day bgwiehle
Unfortunately, I do not have any knowledge of when or where my Grandparents married and if it was before or after they immigrated. I also do not know if they immigrated together or separately - if Newfoundland counted as 'not Canada' at the time.
I did try looking for a marriage certificate with various Canadian archives, but I was unsuccessful. Same for death certificates.

Comment: PolyGeo - regarding your earlier comment in discrepancies between the census and baptismal records, you are correct that they do not match. Since the census was taken in June, then the second daughter should have been counted, but was not. I was assuming the baptismal record had precedence.
Also just noticed the comment about Grandmothers immigration date and US citizenship, I hadn't noticed that on the census record - thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Can I ask where you found your Elizabeth's parents, and how you know you have the right baptism for her? A marriage in Newfoundland might be a possibility, too.

Comment: Hi njkt - Woke up this morning thinking about Grandmother Elizabeth's baptism certificate oddly enough. The date there. also doesn't match the Census - it says Grandmother Elizabeth Hayes was born on 30/11/1890 in St. John's Newfoundland, to John and Jane Hayes. The Baptismal sponsors are John Hayes and Jane Cahill - I assume that's the parent's birth names - although that might be wrong.

Comment: The other possibility is that Elizabeth and James Edward Allan didn't marry - on my Aunt's baptismal 1921 certificate it says the parents are 'James Edward Allan' and 'Elizabeth Hayes' with the sponsors being completely different people. Which questions my original idea that the sponsors on the other certificate are the parents. It's just guesses at this point.

Comment: Baptismal sponsors by definition are not parents - these are the godparents. (John Hayes might be the grandfather of the baby or cousin of the father). It sounds to me like you have found an Elizabeth Hayes baptism, but not necessarily *your* Elizabeth Hayes baptism, unless this certificate has been passed down through the family?

Comment: I think it might be worth you asking a separate question about who tended to fill the roles of baptism sponsors at that time in that location.

Comment: Hi Nkjt - thankfully, the baptismal records of my Grandmother and Aunt are family records. That's all we have though - the rest of the family documentation was destroyed.

Comment: Those draft records look like they will be very useful to you, and are a great find!  I think you should cut and paste the info you found into a self-answer, and then accept the answer by @cleaverkin as being the one that helped you the most.  Then I think you start working on your next question, researching first and then asking here when you are stuck.  I think it would be interesting to know the outcome of James' request for exemption, because if he was turned down, it could provide a possible explanation for his change of countries soon after.

Comment: I wonder whether the local Powell/Florida newspapers reported the draft "results", or commented on anybody leaving town.  If Powell is a small town and he grew up there, then his death anywhere may have been reported there.

Comment: The James and Jesse Allen, whose WWI draft cards you found, are brothers, per 1900 census at https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M36S-BYG and 1910 census at https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MVKW-H5X . James is probably not your ancestor, he is still in Florida in the 1940 census https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VTHL-RGF, with wife Ruth and 4 children, all born in Florida.

Comment: James Allen b. 23/12/1890 is apparently resident in Hernando County, Florida continuously: 1900, 1910 & 1940 in previous  comment. Also 1920 census https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MNYL-241 and 1930 census https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:SR1H-46Z and 1935 Florida census https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MNVP-RYC

Comment: @bgwiehle - Mate, you're good at this. I doubt I'd have been able to find that info. A pity, but that leaves me back were I was.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit of a long shot, but if James Edward Allan was born in the U.S. in 1891 and was still living there in 1918, it's possible (although not certain) that there's a U.S. WWI draft registration card for him.

All males born between a given date in 1877 and a given date in 1897 were required to register for the WWI draft.  It was done pretty much in two passes, one in June 1917 and the second in Sept. 1918.  If James was included in the first pass, there's probably a card for him.

The cards include D.O.B., occupation, marital status and a contact person (for married men usually their wives, for single men usually a parent or sibling).

Names may be misspelled and DOBs are often off by a year, but you might be able to find a short list of viable candidates, with the caveat that if he wasn't recorded in the Jun 1917 batch, he may have emigrated before the second pass happened in Sept. 1918.

WWI draft registrations are on FamilySearch.org:

https://familysearch.org/search/collection/1968530?collectionNameFilter=false

and on Ancestry.com:

http://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=6482

Comment: This is just a thought but would US draft dodging be a reason someone might appear in Canada a few years later with a new name?  I know that there is no evidence for this.

Comment: It's an interesting thought - I don't know how easy it was to avoid registration in 1917, but there are men in my database whose registration cards I've been unable to locate (yet).  I do know that there were avoiders (called "slackers" at the time).  Thousands of them were forcibly conscripted.  Oddly, there were cases of Canadians relocating to the U.S. to avoid the Canadian draft at that time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conscription_Crisis_of_1917

Comment: @cleaverkin - would you know how I might go about searching for a draft card?

Comment: I updated my reply to include links to the collections I know about, there may be other indexes from, e.g., Fold3 or MyHeritage, but these are the ones I've used.